React Native App Failed to build with error message: Building for iOS, but linking in dylib built for iOS-simulator
The app has been working well for a couple of days when I run it on a device, but then I clean build folder did some changes and then it failed to build. I used to be able to run in either from VSCode with yarn ios --device or from XCode, but now both didn't work and gave me the error:
" Building for iOS, but linking in dylib (/User/myName/folderName/appName/node_modules/frameworkName) built for iOS-simulator "
additionally it also shows the error:
"Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
I'm using:

react version 18.2
react native version 0.73.6
x code 15.3
M1 macbook

I didn't use expo, only react native CLI.
One weird thing that I found was in Xcode when I click on the appName.xcodeproj in Project Document section, it shows that Project Format is in XCode 12.
The project did use XCode 12 few weeks ago, but I updated my XCode to 15.3, why is it still showing XCode 12. If I manually change it to XCode 15, doing pod install will cause some errors.
I am happy to provide more info if anyone could help. Thanks in advance
